# Amazon S3: I'm seeing 'Raw Content' stored rather than an image

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm pinging an API which is giving me the path to an image. I am then opening/reading that image and saving it to a database on s3.

The problem is that rather than storing the actual image, it's storing just the words `Raw Content`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my relevant code. Basically I store the path to the file in the field `coverart` and the function `store_in_s3_partpic` returns the path to the file. This function also obviously loads the content to S3.

```
pic = partpics['url']
# CACHING
img_url = pic
name = urlparse(img_url).path.split('/')[-1]
#wrap your file content??
content = ContentFile(urllib2.urlopen(img_url).read())
unipart.coverart = store_in_s3_partpic(name, content)
```

Am I doing anything wrong here that would cause me to just see 'Raw Content'?

Here's my store_in_s3_partpic code:

```
def store_in_s3_partpic(name, content):
    print "STORING PARTPIC"
    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    pathtofile = "partpics/%s" % (name)
    b = conn.create_bucket('mybucket')
    mime = mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = "/media/partpics/%s" % (name)
    k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)
    k.set_contents_from_string(content)
    k.set_acl("public-read")
    return pathtofile
```

Comment: What is the raw content of `urllib2.urlopen(img_url).read()`?

Comment: Uhh.. how do I find that out? Sorry I'm kind of a newbie.

Comment: I did a `print content` statement and it says `Raw Content` also.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you (a) examine the url; and (b) check it out in a browser.

Comment: Thanks @marcin I did and indeed I can open it.

Comment: The problem is that it's not saving the image into S3 properly -- I have also added my S3 code in case that helps...

Comment: So, you can get the actual image in a browser? Then it's not a problem with your storage code, but with your retrieval code. I recommend that you try the `requests` module, which is a much simpler way of making HTTP requests.

Comment: Sorry I meant I could read the paste the `img_url` URL into my browser and look at it there. When I try to view the image through s3 I cannot read it.

Comment: So it follows that the problem is not with what is stored at img url, but with your code which attempts to read it.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with how I'm reading it?

Comment: ipso facto the problem you're seeing, there's something wrong. I can't tell you what it is, not least because I can't get into your running code, and in any case I never use `urllib2`. I use `requests`.

Comment: ok I'm going to try out requests

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the file pointer after I read it? Like perhaps I need to use `seek`?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but I changed the file open command to this and it all works now:

```
        `content = urllib2.urlopen(img_url).read()`
```